# Django Model object creation

Tags: python, django

Look at my django model (I'm pasting here only a part of it):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User as DjangoUser
from django.db import models

class Client(DjangoUser):
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address, blank=True, null=True)
```

I know how to create fresh Client and User:

```
client = Client(username=name, password=pass)
client.save()
```

This code creates two records: user and client, client references user with its foreign key.

In my mysql db there is already a DjangoUser record. And now I want to create Client based on this existing user. How to do this?

Comment: @bartek if the answer that someone gives you isn't correct, you don't have to mark their answer -1.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out how Stackoverflow works, thanks for your -1

Comment: @ken then when should you use -1 ? Of course he should! But putting -1 on the question because the OP set -1 on your answer is revenge, and you should not do that.

Comment: @ken and please, when you have less than 600 rep on a community site, don't tell other what they should do or not do.

Comment: @e-satis: The problem here is that answers **are correct**, but he's downvoting them just because he doesn't like the way Django works.

Comment: if I've devoted something-sorry, I must have clicked something accidentally. I don't know stackoverflow well and I don't know that points and reputation is so important here! @ken I would love to give milion points in plus :) Can i vote it up again?

Comment: @bartek I think you can change you mind, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @e-satis: Dude chill out, I wasn't trying to tell them what to do, I was just letting them know that he didn't need to always put a +1 or -1, I saw that they were new and figured I would give some advice, just trying to be helpful.

Comment: @e-satis -1 is like not -10 on the rep but -1. I got answers going down as much as -26. It's ok, it won't kill you.

Comment: What I do think is a big problem is somebody downvoting HIS question as a revenge. It really is childish. He apologized about being careless, he is honest, asked a clear question. The guy is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User is not abstract, so extending it like that will not work. Rather, you should use composition.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User as DjangoUser
from django.db import models

class ClientDetails(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(DjangoUser)
   address = models.ForeignKey(Address, blank=True, null=True)
```

This pattern is documented here:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users

Comment: thanks for your tip, but I really want to use inheritance because admin panel copies all fields from User do Client and I can edit it in one place. Unless OneToOneField does the same?
If not, I'll use raw sql.

Comment: sorry, you can't do that in Django.

Comment: @bartek I added a link in my answer to address this concern.

Comment: @bartek: Yes, I am sure. The link is to official Django documentation.

Answer (score 5):

`User` is a special case in the Django framework. **You should not use inheritance.**

The best practice to add data to it is to create a model and define it as [user profile](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users):

Create a model for this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True) # ensure you create one profile only
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address, blank=True, null=True)
```

Then you should declare it in the settings as the user profile:

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = "your_app.UserProfile"
```

Then in your view:

```
def your_view(request):
    user_profile = request.user.get_profile()
    address = user_profile.address
```

This is the standard way to do it because Django contrib apps such as the admin, or auth (with login, permissions, etc) will expect the user to be a `User` class and not the subclass you are creating.

If you use inheritance, `request.user` won't be the object you created and you won't be able to access it's data.

If your concern is to be able to edit all data concerning the user in the same page, then there is [a way to do this](http://wolfram.kriesing.de/blog/index.php/2008/customize-admin-for-user-model):

Comment: This is definitely the way to go, I have used this with success in many applications

Answer (score 2):

You could so something like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User as DjangoUser
from django.db import models

class ClientDetails(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(DjangoUser)
   address = models.ForeignKey(Address, blank=True, null=True)
```

And your code to create the object would be something like this:

```
#assuming there is a user with this object already, you should add logic to handle the case when there is no user available.
django_user = DjangoUser.objects.get(username=name)

client = Client(user=django_user, password=pass)
client.save()
```

Or you could do something like this if you want to extend the User, which isn't normally done. You should use profiles for this.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User as DjangoUser
from django.db import models

class ClientDetails(DjangoUser):
   address = models.ForeignKey(Address, blank=True, null=True)
```

And then your client code isn't too much different then you described.

```
#assuming there is a user with this object already, you should add logic to handle the case when there is no user available.
client = Client(username=name, password=pass)
client.save()
```